# SoundPool Loading from URL

Tags: android

I load my mp3 via a path into sound pool. For reasons I don't want to go into I dont want to load via `R.raw`...

But I get the error:

```
play(int, float, float, int, int, float) in the type SoundPool is not  applicable for the arguments (Object, float, float, int, int, float)
```

Is there a way to convert the object to an `int`?

```
SoundPool mySoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
HashMap mySoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
mySoundPoolMap.put(0,  mySoundPool.load("android.resource://com.App.Notifications/raw/myMP3",1));

float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

mySoundPool.play(mySoundPoolMap.get(0), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) docs there are a couple of ways to add something to a sound pool:

1. `load(AssetFileDescriptor afd, int priority)`
2. `load(Context context, int resId, int priority)`
3. `load(String path, int priority)`
4. `load(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length, int priority)`

Because you don't want to load a bundled asset you can't use the either of the first two options. That means you have to use option 3 or 4.

The best option is to probably download the sound file yourself from the url and then save the file and then add the sound to the `SoundPool` using a `FileDescriptor` that points to that file or using the `String` that contains the path of the file.

**Update**: When you add an item to the `SoundPool` using `load` an `int` is returned. This `int` is a [handle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_%28computing%29) to the sound. Then to play the sound you **must use that** `int` to tell the `SoundPool` which sound you want to play:

For example:

```
sp = new SoundPool();
int handle1 = sp.load(/* add sound 1*/);
int handle2 = sp.load(/* add sound 1*/);

sp.play(handle2, /*other args*/); // play sound 2
```

Comment: I try using the string but the play() wants an int, how do I get its id after mySoundPoolMap.put(0,  mySoundPool.load("android.resource://com.App.Notifications/raw/myMP3",1));

Comment: When you call play you have to use the `int` handle returned by the call to `load`. See my update for a brief explanation

Comment: I've tried this, I get no errors, but the sound still doesnt play, any ideas?

Comment: yes you probably aren't loading the sound correctly. Soundpool can't load sounds from a URL.

Comment: you can only use the sound after it's completed loading . you need to use setOnLoadCompleteListener